# Do you have any other alternativ beside Udp6SocketTransport Pysnmp

Tags: python, linux, windows, ipv6, pysnmp

I am trying to make a program that can use IPv6 in Pysnmp and I already read a lot from google and so on.

And I always found that people use `Udp6SocketTransport`. but the problem is this class does not work on all platform and I need it so it might work on Windows and Linux.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 support in pysnmp is fully dependent on its platform support. So if Udp6SocketTransport class works on one platform but does not work on another - chances are the platform lacks IPv6 support.

Could you check that:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.has_ipv6
True
>>>
```

?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want info/examples on how to access IPv6 with Pysnmp both on windows and linux. Please do the needful. (Note: Error pysnmp.error.PySnmpError: IPv6 not supported by platform)

Answer (score 0):

Have you [installed IPv6](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2478747) into your Windows machine? I assume it's a Windows XP.

Comment: Yes, with normal cmd. I can ping other website with IPv6 and I can also ping my other PC with IPv6 and the only problem is that I cannot connect to other IPv6 with Method Udp6SocketTransport.

Comment: Does your Python installation supports IPv6? What is the value of the "socket.has_ipv6" flag?

Comment: >>> import socket
>>> socket.has_ipv6
True
>>>